# JobIntentService job ID globally unique or scoped by the class?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobintentservice

Documentation implies it's scoped per the service class:

> A unique job ID for scheduling; must be the same value for all work
>   enqueued for the same class.

However, I have two services with their `JOB_ID`, and `enqueWork()` as:

```
  companion object {
    private const val JOB_ID = 1

    fun enqueueWork(context: Context, action: String) {
      enqueueWork(context, Svc1::class.java, JOB_ID, Intent(action))
    }
  }
```

and

```
  companion object {
    private const val JOB_ID = 1

    fun enqueueWork(context: Context, action: String) {
      enqueueWork(context, Svc2::class.java, JOB_ID, Intent(action))
    }
  }
```

when I start both the services at boot (probably around the same time) `Svc2` runs 2x. Changing `Svc2`'s JOB_ID to 2 solves the problem.

If it's NOT scoped by the service class, that's awful as it means every service needs to be aware of the implementation of every other service in the same app.

?